# Cypress test hangs forever when system throws an unexpected alert during the test

Tags: javascript, cypress

When Web application unexpectedly throws an error by alert box
Cypress test hangs/stuck forever and test never gets completed or failed until user manually closes the browser or manually click on the OK button of alert box.

[image]

I have a below sample HTML page to reproduce the issue, Here I am explicitly throwing the alert box after 5 seconds of the page load.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Button Alert Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="changeLabel()">Click me for a label</button>
  <p id="label"></p>

  <iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>

  <script>
    // Show alert after 5 seconds of page load within the frame
    setTimeout(function() {
      var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
      frame.style.display = 'block';
      frame.contentWindow.alert("Error While Processing Request");
    }, 5000);

    function changeLabel() {
      document.getElementById('label').innerText = "You clicked the button!";
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Below is the Cypress test to reproduce the issue:**

```
describe('Reproduce Alert Test', () => {
  it('Handle alert in a Frame', () => {
    cy.visit('/alert-test.html');
    cy.wait(6000)

    // Verify page title
    cy.title().should('eq', 'Alert Example');

    // Click the button and verify the label
    cy.get('button').contains('Click me for a label').click();
    cy.get('#label').should('have.text', 'You clicked the button!');
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** Issue gets reproduced when the webpage contains the `iFrame`, Without `iFrame` Cypress automatically accepts the alert message.

Comment: `alert()` is _synchronous_ and _blocks further script execution_ until the visitor happens to click "OK". Read it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [cy.stub()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub#Replace-built-in-window-methods-like-prompt) on the `<iframe>` window will handle the alert and allow the test to proceed.

I've also added an assertion that checks the stub received a call.

```js
let stub;
cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/alert.html')

cy.get('iframe#myFrame')
  .its('0.contentWindow')
  .then(win => {
    stub = cy.stub(win, 'alert')
  })
  
cy.then(() => {
  // this needs to be inside a then callback 
  // because stub is set asynchronously
  cy.wrap(stub, {timeout:6_000}).should('have.been.called')
})

cy.title().should('eq', 'Button Alert Example')

cy.get('button').contains('Click me for a label').click();
cy.get('#label').should('have.text', 'You clicked the button!')
```

Here's the log of the test:

[image]

---

#### Real world iframe

In a real-world app, you might not get so lucky with simple iframe code as above.

Using [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) will make the test more reliable.

Comment: That doesn't work, If you wait for the popup for 5 seconds. add wait cy.wait(6000) after cy.visit(), Issue still occurs.

Comment: Change the stub to the `<iframe>` window, since that is where the alert comes from.

Comment: Yes that worked, But here I am explicitly triggering the alert box, when alert box is expected then we can handle it, But my actual use case is different, When Cypress tests is running I click on Submit/Save button, System successfully submit/save the request,  But sometimes (May be 1 out of 10 times) it throws above alert when something went wrong. 
So we don't know whether it will throw the error or submit the request successfully, Is there any way we can implement a listener that listen to such event whenever it occurs, As in my case it happens randomly or a random page or request.

Comment: I agree that's tricky when the test is non-deterministic. The `cy.stub()` is Sinon stub which has `.calls()` property you can use instead of `.should('have.been.called')` to check in a non-failing way, but you have to program your own retry loop to check for the alert that maybe never occurs.

Comment: It might be better to use a `cy.intercept()` to stub the submit request and you can have a deterministic test for both scenarios, when the submit fails + alert occurs. and 2nd test where the submit is successful.